# selecting different options from two different drop down menu in Selenium

Tags: selenium

How can I select different options from different drop down menus?
after selecting an option from second menu, first drop down menu gets the default value which is first option.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/select/option[2]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div/div[3]/div/select/option[2]").click()
```

Comment: Please add the HTML for the `<select>`s.  We can help you with much better selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div/div[3]/div"))).selectByIndex(2);
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div/div[3]/div"))).selectByIndex(2);
```